# Join metrics on a field & time in Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-transform

I have 2 metrics regarding CI pipelines whose values are respectively the duration of a pipeline (so far) and its id.

I'd like to join them on the time and a "reference" (the branch) as, at one point in time, for a certain branch of the pipeline, there is only one pipeline running.

I've tried to use grafana transform functions such as `join by field` but with no success.

If you want to know, my final goal is measure the max duration by id to see our the duration evolve in time by branch.

Here is a table representation of those metrics:

Metrics pipeline_duration_seconds

| time | ref | metrics value (duration in sec) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/12/2023 11:32 | migration | 30 |
| 01/12/2023 11:32 | migration | 20 |
| 01/12/2023 11:31 | migration | 0 |
| 01/12/2023 11:32 | daily | 45 |
| 01/12/2023 11:32 | daily | 15 |
| 01/12/2023 11:31 | daily | 0 |

Metrics pipeline_id

| time | ref | metrics value (pipeline_id) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/12/2023 11:32 | migration | 1244 |
| 01/12/2023 11:32 | migration | 1244 |
| 01/12/2023 11:31 | migration | 1244 |
| 01/12/2023 11:32 | daily | 1123 |
| 01/12/2023 11:32 | daily | 1123 |
| 01/12/2023 11:31 | daily. | 1123 |

Desired output table:

| time | ref | pipeline_id | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/12/2023 11:32 | migration | 1244 | 30 |
| 01/12/2023 11:32 | migration | 1244 | 20 |
| 01/12/2023 11:31 | migration | 1244 | 0 |
| 01/12/2023 11:32 | daily | 1123 | 45 |
| 01/12/2023 11:32 | daily | 1123 | 15 |
| 01/12/2023 11:31 | daily | 1123 | 0 |